# Time based access to documents

Tags: access

I am trying to provide time based access to sharepoint 2013 document library to users.

1. I will have my documents in Sharepoint library
2. I have to provide time based access permissions to sharepoint doucument library
   For example :- John should be able to access the documents from nov 26th to no 30th. After that when he tries to access the document he should get unauthorized error.

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this is by creating a timer job that will run periodically and modify documents permissions. You can use another list or SQL table to specify the permissions. 
For example that list would have the following fields:

```
Documents (lookup field, multi values allowed)
Start Time (DateTime field)
EndTime (DateTime field)
PermissionType (choice field)
Users (User or Group field, multi values allowed)
```

… and other fields as needed

The timer job can get the info from this list and set the permissions on the documents.

Comment: Thanks Naim. Can we use the usergroup.asmx from sharepoint to set the permissions at document level automatically?

Comment: If you create a timer job you work with server side code and you don’t need services. For setting permissions with servcies Permissions.asmx is there but only for List or Web level permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Office 13 Information Rights Management will handle timed expiry of data with ease but its a big subject and requires a lot of planning. [Technet Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179103.aspx#BKMK_WhatIsIRM)